# Why there is no BooleanConsumer in Java 8?

Tags: java, function, java-8

I'm afraid that this is somewhat a silly question.

Is there anybody can tell me why there is no `BooleanConsumer` opposite to [`BooleanSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html)?

Is there any reason other than "because simply there isn't"?

Should I create my own one? Or am I missing something else?

```java
public interface BooleanConsumer {

    void accept(boolean value);

    default BooleanConsumer andThen(final BooleanConsumer after) {
        return v -> {
            accept(v);
            after.accept(v);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

Where to use? I'm writing a library that uses much of consumers and suppliers. I successfully wrote a line with `LongConsumer` and I encountered a situation that expecting a consumer accepting a boolean value which is from a method result. Say `Files.deleteIfExist`?

Comment: Where would you use a BooleanConsumer?

Comment: For what it's worth, there's also no `BooleanPredicate` or `BooleanFunction<R>`.

Comment: Another aspect is that with `Consumer<Boolean>` there's always that niggling question "do I have to check for null" since `Boolean` sometimes get (ab)used as tri-state values. With `BooleanConsumer` there'd be no such concern.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`IntConsumer` and `LongConsumer` are needed to avoid the overhead autoboxing every value. It is much more efficent to be working on raw primitives.
However, for Boolean and Byte every possible object is cached so there is little reason to avoid using `Consumer<Boolean>` or `Consumer<Byte>`

Comment: Well, boxing and unboxing adds some computational overhead even without object allocation, and objects also require more memory than primitives. This answer also does not explain why there is no "CharConsumer".

Comment: @lbalazscs with object elation, there is no boxing/unbox which is rather the point. For the stack the size of the boolean is actually a 32 bit int value whereas the size of a reference to a cached object is typically also 32 bit. I think it does explain why there is no CharConsumer as there is very little performance benefit.

Comment: What do you mean by "object elation"? (I never heard of this, nor did Google...).

Comment: @lbalazscs in java it is a feature of escape analysis. Instead of allocating an object on the heap it places it on the stack. The word should have been elision as in lock elision.

Comment: I see, you mean that if escape analysts determines that the object can be allocated on the stack, then it could be enough to allocate its fields, without the object metadata. But if the autoboxing can be optimized away, then I don't understand the "IntConsumer and LongConsumer are needed to avoid the overhead autoboxing every value" part of your answer.

Comment: @lbalazscs I believe the primitives consumers are there to support an API which has additional methods like sum, min, max

Comment: @lbalazscs Late reply, but take a look at the source of  `Byte`, internal class `ByteCache`: This contains "pre-boxed" singletons for each byte value. When a byte is "auto-boxed" it calls `Byte.valueOf` (getting a cached object) not `new Byte()`, and thus avoid any dynamic memory allocation at all. There are too many `Int`s and `Long`s to do the same trick for every value, but it is still done for a small commonly-used sub-range around 0.

Comment: Hah! 7 years later I have the same query. There's a downside of `Consumer<Boolean>` - it takes 3 possible values (including `null`) not just 2. So I would generally only want to use it in cases I really expect null to be handled as well.

Answer (score 15):

As other answers indicate there is no great reason to avoid `Consumer<Boolean>`, but then there's no great reason to avoid `Supplier<Boolean>` either, so a different explanation is required for this.

A similar question is why can't you switch on a `boolean` value. The answer is that there's no need because you could always use `if` or `if else`.

A `BooleanConsumer` would really be nothing more than an `if else` construct because the `accept()` method for a `BooleanConsumer` could always be written in this form:

```
if (v) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

If you needed to pass such code around as data, you could just pass a pair of `Runnable`s representing "do something" and "do something else". In many cases, you would only need one of the `Runnable`s because one of the two blocks above would be empty.

In the same way, there is no need for a `BooleanPredicate` because it would be nothing more than a pair of `BooleanSupplier`s and there is no need for a a `BooleanFunction<R>` because it would be nothing more than a pair of `Supplier<R>`s.

In contrast to this, it is not possible to break a `BooleanSupplier` into two simpler objects.

Comment: But then you need to handle two items instead of one. Wouldn't it be more convenient if you just had one? Similarly, why do we need a  `BooleanSupplier`?

Comment: Seems like a stretch.

Comment: Downvoted, this answer is misleading. Yes, `if` is one use case, but more often than not, it's about assigning the value (think boolean properties, just count how many places any value is moved through before it's actually looked at).

Answer (score 8):

You can write your own BooleanConsumer, but in order to make it really useful, you would need to write your own BooleanStream, too. There is an IntStream, LongStream, and DoubleStream, but no "BooleanStream" (or "ShortStream", "FloatStream" etc). It seems that these primitives were judged not to be important enough.

You can always use Boolean objects instead of boolean primitives, and a Boolean Consumer to consume the values. Example code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Boolean> myConsumer = b -> System.out.println("b = " + b);

        Stream.of("aa", "bb", "cc")
                .map(Main::myBooleanFunction)
                .forEach(myConsumer);

    }

    static boolean myBooleanFunction(String s) {
        return s.startsWith("b");
    }
}
```

myBooleanFunction returns a boolean, but using it in a map creates a stream of Booleans (because we are in the generic, non-primitive Stream. Again, we have mapToInt, mapToLong, mapToDouble to create an IntStream etc, but no mapToBoolean).

If you don't need stream support, you can still write and use a "BooleanConsumer" in order to provide a type for some behavior, put I would prefer to see a functional interface with a more specific and descriptive name.